# flutter navigation replacement keep old page until animation is finished

Tags: flutter, animation, navigator

I use navigator.push to go to NewPage() from oldPage() onpress event:

```
Navigator.of(context).push(
   PageRouteBuilder(
   opaque: false,
   pageBuilder: (context, animation, _) {
      return NewPage();
}),
);
```

The NewPage code: (also the tween animation)

```
class NewPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NewPageState createState() => _NewPageState();
}

class _NewPageState extends State<NewPage> {
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TweenAnimationBuilder(
      tween: Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0),
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1500),
      child: Scaffold(...),
      builder: (context, value, child) {
        return  ShaderMask(...) }
```

It works fine. The animation keeps the old page in the background while the NewPage takes over. However, sometimes I need to use pushReplacement to get rid of the oldpage. When I use pushReplacement, the old page is removed immediately and can't be seen during the animation. how can I make it to remove the old page only after the animation is done?

should I let it go through with push, then remove the old one manually in initState() of the NewPage()?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use your own PageRouteBuilder for such Animations. The following article describes the usage of it:
https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/animation/page-route-animation